# load plugin in code snippet

Tags: plugins, php, code

I'm using "PHP code snippet" in my WordPress website to create a "form" so i can read and write back to my database.

Is there a way i can make a "text-area" with style editing options instead of plain text? or perhaps a work around or alternative ?

Comment: I'm not sure we can provide an answer without seeing what you use now,

Comment: maybe you could just use `wp_editor()` in the form? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor